# Filter MySQL information for data compare

Tags: php, mysql, filter, compare

I am running a data comparison and seem to have an issue with numeric comparisons.

Everything in the database is stored as a varchar and I am using the following code
to filter and compare.

```
$record['oldvalue'] = '"' . strtoupper(trim(str_replace(array("\n", "\r", '"'), '', $source))) . '"'; 
$record['newvalue'] = '"' . strtoupper(trim(str_replace(array("\n", "\r", '"'), '', $compare))) . '"';

if ($record['oldvalue'] != $record['newvalue']) {$record['difference'] = "Y";}
else {$record['difference'] = "N";}
```

All non numeric and partially numeric fields return fine with this.
However dates and numbers return a false difference. (when checked manually the fields appear identical in the data base and on output)

Im sure its just something I have not filtered for, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `var_dump($record['oldvalue'])` and `var_dump($record['newvalue'])` and take a look at if you can see the difference.

It might be trailing space or floating point rounding or something else.